# When can I remove entries in svn:mergeinfo?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, mergeinfo

I've used TortoiseSVN for several years.

Several branches were created, merged back to trunk, and then deleted.

Example of deleted branches:

> https://SvnServer/svn/MyProject/branches/branch1
>   https://SvnServer/svn/MyProject/branches/branch2
>   https://SvnServer/svn/MyProject/branches/branch3

The svn:mergeinfo of the trunk (https://SvnServer/svn/MyProject/trunk) still contains those merge tracking info for those deleted branches.

Example of svn:mergeinfo:

> /branches/branch1:2106-2146
>   /branches/branch2:1983-2028
>   /branches/branch3:1698-1741

Are these info still necessary? Can I remove them from svn:mergeinfo property?

Answer (score 0):

Are they a problem? I would Just leave them, we have loads and loads of them on our Trunk.
You never know if you may need to see which revisions of a branch were merged into the trunk. 
Also, the braches can still be viewed using the Repo Browser and just picking the revision before they were deleted.

Comment: Sometimes it DO casue the problem. when I create new branch and at the moment to merge it back. I can not use "Reintegrate a branch" option and have to select "Merge two different trees".